# How do I resize the screen of Parrot Sec in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, screen-resolution, parrot-os, virtualbox-guest-additions

I have searched and found the VirtualBox Guest Addons fix, but that isn't working for me. Every time I resize the window in the VirtualBox settings and/or the Display Settings in Parrot Security, it initially resizes to what I want but reverts back to the 800x600 square default (both the VB machine (if in scaled mode) and the Parrot Sec display, although the display settings still *say* that they are in the higher resolution - see the screenshot below which shows a VirtualBox screen expanded to fit my display, with a Parrot Sec display resized to 1280x800 but only showing as 800x600.
If I click where my mouse is in the screenshot, the window briefly goes to 1280x800 only to drop back to 800x600 a fraction of a second later.

[image: Screenshot of VirtualBox in Full Screen showing an 800x600 viewing area in the middle]

Answer (score 3):

After installing VirtualBox Guest Additions, in your guest machine, open a terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11
```

If it asks you about keeping a file or installing the new one, press I to select the new one/package maintainer's version;

```
sudo VBoxClient --clipboard
```

Installing virtualbox-guest-x11 package also resolves the issue where the shared folders are not visible.

And installing this package (and rebooting the virtual machine) also resolves the guest window not auto-resizing when the VM window is resized.

This also resolves the issue where paste after a reboot no longer works and the `sudo VBoxClient --clipboard` command needs to be repeated. After installing VirtualBox-guest-x11, the `--clipboard` command does not need to be repeated after each reboot.